# Execute maven-based end-to-end-tests and display result in Tekton Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, e2e-testing, tekton

Our end-to-end tests are based on maven/CucumberJVM.
All artifacts are built using Jenkins and are saved in Artifactory.
Then tekton should for one (or more) environments

- take over and set up the infrastructure (pods, ingress, configmaps, etc.) using helm
- run the Cucumber-end-to-end-tests on the environment
- **display the results**
- succeed or fail&clean up.

How would I display results from a test-run? In Tekton Dashboard? Are there plugins for that already? Is it possible to display static html-files as a result of a testrun there?

Thanks in advance for any hint.
Best regards,
Ingo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tekton Dashboard maintainer here; I think this is an awesome idea.

So with regards to viewing results (you mention running the build in Jenkins, but you could use Maven in a Tekton Pipeline too), while Jenkins has a bunch of plugins and can store artifacts (like test results), we're lacking for the Tekton Dashboard right now. Perhaps we provide clickable links to somewhere, but then I'm worried about default browsers for showing XML/JSON etc. Obviously just printing (to stdout, for a Task) the html/xml etc isn't great.

I've raised this in our Tekton Slack's Dashboard channel (for convenience here's a [link](https://github.com/tektoncd/community/blob/master/contact.md#slack) to join) and I expect we'll make an issue for discussing this properly over on [GitHub](https://github.com/tektoncd/dashboard/issues) for anyone to easily follow and track discussions on.

FYI we have [weekly working groups](https://github.com/tektoncd/community/blob/master/working-groups.md) for all Tekton projects that anyone is welcome to join and we could discuss this in more depth there too.

Happy to provide an update here once there is an outcome, there isn't a way to do this in a great way right now.

Update: one of our core maintainers and contributors has suggested https://github.com/tektoncd/dashboard/issues/895 being the issue you are looking for!

Comment: Hi Adam! That's exactly the info I needed. And I guess issue 895 might indeed be one early increment that would help already. I'll continue the discussion there.